# Pandas How do I merge the dataframe using for-loop without getting Nan errors

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, for-loop, nan

This is the original data.

```
pbr2=[PBR -list of companies -DataFrame]

      KIS    Stock 20100129 20100226 20100331 20100430  20100531
0   001402  036460  1.01    0.98     0.73     0.69     0.65 
1   001471  033780  2.66    2.52     2.34     2.09     2.25 
3   041800  035720  5.58    5.55     4.51     4.46     5.26 
4   064847  032640  1.28    1.10     1.06     1.15     1.07 
5   086512  069960  1.54    1.51     1.37     1.32     1.43
```

I have created a sorting function to sort multiple columns easily.
I have also created a for loop to repeat the `sort_it` function to iterate on multiple columns.

```
def sort_it(num):
  df = pd.DataFrame(pbr2.iloc[:,[1,num]])
  df = df.sort_values(df.columns[1])
  return df


for i in range(4,10):
  df = sort_it(i)
  if i ==4:
    total_df =df
  else:
    total_df =pd.concat([total_df,df])
```

The problem is that when I use `sort_it` individually, it outputs it correctly without showing NANs in the data. However, if I use the for loop
it turns out almost all of the data turns into a NAN. Like this:

```
    Stock   20100331 20100430 20100531  20100630 20100730 20100831  
87  016380  0.38        NaN       NaN     NaN     NaN      NaN
18  049770  0.43        NaN       NaN     NaN     NaN      NaN
47  003240  0.47        NaN.      NaN     NaN     NaN       NaN
```

I need the result to be:
What I want is to sort_value(ascending-order) for each column using a for-loop. Like the example of sort_it(4) for each column.

```
    KIS     Stock 20100129 20100226 20100331 20100430 20100531  
0   001402  036460  1.01    0.98    0.73     0.69     0.65  
1   001471  033780  2.66    2.52    2.34     2.09     2.25  
3   041800  035720  5.58    5.55    4.51     4.46     5.26  
4   064847  032640  1.28    1.10    1.06     1.15     1.07  
5   086512  069960  1.54    1.51    1.37     1.32     1.43

sort_it(4)
     Stock  20100331
87  016380  0.38
18  049770  0.43
47  003240  0.47
52  007700  0.47
... ... ...
131 051600  5.08
22  051900  8.81
```

Comment: Also I cannot see all dates `20100129 20100226 20100331 20100430`, is possible change it ?

Comment: 03460. These are ticker numbers  for Kospi (Korean stock market)

Comment: Yes, no data changed. If it helps the original data has 144rows*137columns. But, the structure is the same with the current subset data.

Comment: what is dfout=dfin ?  The output is sorted. It is in ascending order.

Comment: It seems not understand. Try forget for your real data. You need working only with posted in question. So you cannot add ouput from real data, only from data in question. So can you change it? From last edit no Stock, only matching `20100331`, all values, all Stock are different. So how I can underdtand what need?

Comment: Also I need what is `total_df` only from input data posted in question.

Comment: Maybe help [how to provide a great pandas example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples)

Comment: It would help if you had a clearer input / expected output here. As of now, it's quite unclear what you want to achieve.